# Metal clad (MC) cable: cut or rearrange it? Plus other questions on the options to install it

Tags: wire, cables, cable-management

I need 6 feet of metal clad (MC) cable. The stores only sell 25. Is it possible to buy only what I need?

If not, may I just hang the extra wire, or I must cut it to the length I need?

The only option to secure a MC cable is using metal brackets? Or I can put it in a raceway? The raceway in this case must be metal or can be a plastic raceway?

If I cut, must I use an anti-short brush or it is allowed to leave it without?

If I must use an anti-short, does these usually come with the packaged cable (found in home improvement stores) or must bought separately?

If bought separately, what would be the correct size for a MC cable 12/3?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of any place that sells it other than a roll. But you usually can purchase metallic and non metallic liquid tight by the foot and put the wire inside that. 
There are both metal and plastic straps to secure MC.
I would say why even use MC if you are putting it in a raceway.

Usually there is a bag of anti short bushings with the roll look and make sure you get them and yes you need to use them unless the fitting has this built in.
 Inspectors do look for the bushing as many diy’s don’t know they are required.

Comment: "why even use MC if you are putting it in a raceway": as far as I know I can't put wire inside a plastic raceway, right? It must be metal. If I have to use metal, then I'd just use MC cable. Just to give context I'm wiring from a ceiling light to a a new surface mounted outlet. I don't think I can use a plastic raceway from the light to the outlet, with 3x12 gauge THHN wires inside.

Comment: No there are many non metallic raceway systems. Pvc conduit (not water pipe) it is normally gray it comes in schedule 40 & 80, 80 is used out where the conduit can be damaged  sch 40 inside may be just what you need, but there are other types liquid tight flexible non metallic conduit all plastic and it can be purchased by the foot and can be used in more places than some MC.  You did not say what you are doing but if inside a wall for example smurf tube of flexible non metallic conduit, this stuff is like a straw often blue used inside walls for conductors like THHN. Hope this gives ideas ask

Answer (score 0):

### You have it backwards

The issue is that practically speaking, you can't put most *cables* in a raceway because they gobble up gobsmacking amounts of *raceway fill* (the primary exception being *tray cables*, but those aren't used much for things we deal with around here).  Raceway (conduit) systems are *intended* to be used with individual wires inside them, so I would get 3 lengths of 12AWG THHN in appropriate colors to go inside the raceway, instead.